# Adding a line in a method block of java code using python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, code-editor

I have a lot of java files wherein I have to search for a method, if present I have to add a line inside this method "If this line does not already exist". This line has to be added before the closing brace of the method.

So far I have the following code:

```
import os
import ntpath
extensions = set(['.java','.kt'])
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("/src/main"):
        for file in files:
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
            extension = os.path.splitext(filepath)[1]
            if extension in extensions:
                if 'onCreate(' in open(filepath).read():
                        print (ntpath.basename(filepath))
                        if 'onPause' in open (filepath).read():
                            print ("is Activity and contains onPause\n")
                            #Check if Config.pauseCollectingLifecycleData(); is in this code bloack, if exists do nothing, if does not exist add to the end of code block before }
                        if 'onResume' in open (filepath).read():
                            print ("is Activity and contains onResume\n")
                            #Check if Config.resumeCollectingLifecycleData(); is in this code bloack, if exists do nothing, if does not exist add to the end of code block before }
```

But I am not sure where to go from here, Python not being my first language. Could I request to be guided in the right direction.

Example: 
I am looking for a method with the following signature:

```
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   // Add my line here
}

public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   Config.pauseCollectingLifecycleData(); // Line exists do nothing 
}
```

Comment: Don't read the file multiple times. After `if extension in extensions`, read the file content into a variable and use `in` on that variable: `sourcecode = open(filepath).read()` and then `if "onPause" in sourcecode`. Much faster, much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite difficult. First of all, your `if "onPause" in sourcecode` approach currently doesn't distinguish between *defining* `onPause()` and *calling* it. And second of all, finding the correct closing `}` isn't trivial. Naively, you might just count opening and closing curlies (`{` increments the blocklevel, `}` decrements it), and assume that the `}` that makes the blocklevel zero is the closing curly of the method. However, this might be wrong! Because the method might contain some *string* *literal* containing (possibly unbalanced) curlies. Or *comments* with curlies. This would mess up the blocklevel count.

To do this properly, you would have to build an actual Java parser. That's a lot of work, even when using libraries such as [tatsu](https://pypi.org/project/tatsu/).

If you're fine with a rather volatile [kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge), you can try and use the blocklevel count mentioned above together with the indentation as a clue (assuming your source code is decently indented). Here's something I've hacked up as a starting point:

```
def augment_function(sourcecode, function, line_to_insert):
    in_function = False
    blocklevel = 0
    insert_before = None
    source = sourcecode.split("\n")
    for line_no, line in enumerate(source):
        if in_function:
            if "{" in line:
                blocklevel += 1
            if "}" in line:
                blocklevel -= 1
                if blocklevel == 0:
                    insert_before = line_no
                    indent = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(" ")) + 4  #4=your indent level
                    break
        elif function in line and "public " in line:
            in_function = True
            if "{" in line:
                blocklevel += 1
    if insert_before:
        source.insert(insert_before, " "*indent + line_to_insert)
    return "\n".join(source)

# test code:
java_code = """class Foo {
    private int foo;
    public void main(String[] args) {
        foo = 1;
    }
    public void setFoo(int f)
    {
        foo = f;
    }
    public int getFoo(int f) {
        return foo;
    }
}
"""
print(augment_function(java_code, "setFoo", "log.debug(\"setFoo\")"))
```

Note that this is vulnerable to all sorts of edge cases (such as `{` in a string or in a comment, or tab indent instead of space, or possibly a thousand other things). This is just a starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks man, Been long -- I ended up using the IDE's search and regex facilities :) nevertheless that is a beauty you've written!